# mpdf funciona en local pero en hosting no

Tags: php, phpmailer, composer, mpdf

He revisado varias preguntas similares aquí en SOes, pero sigo sin solucionar mi problema.

Tengo un formulario en mi sitio, este formulario lo escribo en PDF usando mPDF, luego ese mismo PDF es enviado por correo electrónico.
Cuando lo ejecuto en localhost funciona de maravilla, se crea el PDF y el mismo es enviado a mi correo; pero al subir el proyecto en mi hosting no me funciona, tampoco me muestra un error. Adjunto imágenes.

A tener en cuenta:

1. Instale mPDF y PHPmailer usando composer de forma local y subí las carpetas a mi hosting una vez instalado.

*Lo hice así porque no tengo acceso por ssh del sitio.

2. Utilizo Mailtrap para testing de correos.

Alguien me puede dar una idea del porque sucede esto y que documento leer para solucionarlo?

Gracias

[image: Php y Mpdf requeridos]
[image: En la consola no me despliega ningun error, pero mi pagina no envia el correo]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], para que la pregunta sea bien recibida añade el código, errores y demás como texto, no utilices imágenes si no es imprescindible ya que dificultan la lectura entre otras y habrá muchos usuarios como yo ignoremos este tipo de preguntas en las que nos dificultan proporcionar ayuda. Puedes revisar [ask]

Comment: @Xerif muchas gracias, a lo largo de este dia voy a modificar la pregunta, muchas gracias por la recomendacion. Saludos.